# How does GeoServer render Super or MegaTile?

Tags: geoserver, tiles

I'm working on chopping up a big mega map tile into smaller tiles at various zoom level. I'm surrounded with a problem first up in terms of how to get my big mega map tile with all the legends (with more than vector layer overlayed on top of a base map), symbols and text  into GeoServer so that I can say I'm have done the input to GeoServer and ready to cut that input (my mega map tile) into smaller tiles.

And how would GeoServer maintain all the styles, colors and labels etc. from the database?

GeoServer reads a variety of data formats, including:

```
PostGIS
Oracle Spatial
ArcSDE
DB2
MySQL
Shapefiles
GeoTIFF
GTOPO30
ECW, MrSID
JPEG
```

But how does GeoServer read all this?

The documentation is talking about WMS server so shall I assume that a WMS is first stood up to fetch data from the database and inputs to GeoServer in one of the above formats mentioned ( as far as GeoTiFF, JPEG are concerned)?

But then what about fetching data from Oracle Spatial kind of database, how does GeoServer read data out of oracle?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.